# Regular expression to replace spaces and letters and numbers?

Tags: shell, vi

I was wondering if there are any simple vi commands to take the following  as input and get the output mentioned below?I am trying to find a simpler way to take the given as input and get the expected output?
INPUT1:

```
 CoreCapture    6fabc0f7591ae8d4b73aab1e6875026240d02922 (6fabc0f7)
 IOdmgLoader    ddc205a776a0ff3abb3ccd19b9100c8c4ecc6527 (ddc205a7)
 TestPortFamily 0a6fadcf27a5e424bfdb355428f720c76a0fa0c9 (0a6fadcf)
 TestPortCoreCOM    84521ebf0edcc9f24b004dca7ee59f082912bcc7 (84521ebf)
 TechCloudSyncEngine    3ef603e2c6311ed66619309f305574cfc42d8969 (3ef603e2)
 TestPort   34e12f3229b42b441f4a79297d7257387ec71e47 (34e12f32)
 TechVelocity   e3abcce015a0b656d1895c764572fc5db74a0342 (e3abcce0)
 TechnologyUtilities    01c5333f18ced7e2999f9d81b97e75adf0b52319 (01c5333f)
 SPTestPortReporter 0ded7780e104798e7f6b51fc4acfef1de18cebcb (0ded7780)
 VendorCOM  8b153b85627fd26e09d3c72b08a8a0d057276d02 (8b153b85)
 ComvendorCOMV3 e88c71b7f6eba361961ce90809f81e5c8072b1ed (e88c71b7)
 vendorCOMSoftware_Dingo2_4364_Olympic_Bin  73f8c673914706dd22b9c7e946c350982966732b (73f8c673)
 vendorCOMSoftware_Dingo2_4355_Olympic_Bin  0d3f2b9bf0cde2973f44b64d2da36eda7f042e21 (0d3f2b9b)
 TestPortDrivercommode  8f227d2789c67f82d69f75adb06679c94d56ed33 (8f227d27)
 NetworkUtility 15beb21f8d8aae7281d9dd0460850c01f7a80770 (15beb21f)
```

INPUT2:

```
 CoreCapture    branchname (6fabc0f7)
 IOmazeLoader  branchname (ddc205a7)
 GaaliPortFamily  branchname (0a6fadcf)
 GaaliPortCoreTECH        branchname (84521ebf)
 TechCloudSyncEngine    branchname (3ef603e2)
 GaaliPort        branchname (34e12f32)
 TechVelocity   branchname (e3abcce0)
 ConnUtilities      branchname (01c5333f)
 SPGaaliPortReporter      branchname (0ded7780)
 vendorTECH   branchname (8b153b85)
 ComvendorTECHV3 branchname (0770f3c1)
 vendorTECHFirm_Dingo2_4364_company_Bin        branchname (73f8c673)
 vendorTECHFirm_Dingo2_4355_company_Bin        branchname (0d3f2b9b)
 GaaliPortDriverBrcmNIC   branchname (8f227d27)
 NetworkUtility branchname (15beb21f)
 ConnCoexManager    macOS-Tech-QA-Root (8189ef53)
```

OUTPUT:-

```
CoreCapture:6fabc0f7
IOdmgLoader:ddc205a7
TestPortFamily:0a6fadcf
TestPortCoreCOM:84521ebf
TechCloudSyncEngine:3ef603e2
TestPort:34e12f32
TechVelocity:e3abcce0
TechnologyUtilities:01c5333f
SPTestPortReporter:0ded7780
VendorCOM:8b153b85
ComvendorCOMV3:e88c71b7
vendorCOMSoftware_Dingo2_4364_Olympic_Bin:73f8c673
vendorCOMSoftware_Dingo2_4355_Olympic_Bin:0d3f2b9b
TestPortDrivercommode:8f227d27
NetworkUtility:15beb21f
```

I tried running the following commands on a vi editor but doesn't seem to work, any pointers what would be correct regular expression?

```
\s(.*)//
[a-zA-Z0-9]+//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `vim`, you can use this substitution:

```
%s/\v^\s*(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\((\S+)\).*/\1:\2/
```

**Explanation:**

- `:%s`: Match substitution on all the lines
- `\v`: enable very magic
- `^`: Line start
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more leading spaces
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters and capture it in group #1
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `\(`: Match literal `(`
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters and capture it in group #2
- `\)`: Match literal `)`
- `.*`: Match anything after this

**Substitution:**

- `\1:\2`: Backreference #1 followed by colon followed by backreference #2

Without very magic you can use:

```
%s/^\s*\(\S\+\)\s\+\S\+\s\+(\(\S\+\)).*/\1:\2/
```

Comment: I get a `E486: Pattern not found: \v^(\S+)\s+(\S{8}).*`

Comment: my vm is `version 8.0.642 ` ..I have the input in a text file and open it using vi <Text file name>

Comment: did this work for you,I keep getting patter not found even without very magic

Comment: The problem was there was a space at the starting of everyone..can we account for that aswell?if space is present remove that aswell

Comment: If there is a leading space then use: `%s/^\s*\(\S\+\)\s\+\(\S\{8\}\).*/\1:\2/`

Comment: I was wondering  if we can make this regex more generic by matching whatever is in the paranthesis after Matching the  1+ whitespace characters ,it will work for input#2 above..

Comment: Try this one: `%s/\v^\s*(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\((\S+)\).*/\1:\2/`